# Regular expression to match at least character and more words

Tags: java, regex

I am new at programming Java and using Regular Expressions.

I am trying to learn more about regular expressions, and I have the following question.

I want to create a regex that will:

- match at least 2 characters
- match multiple words
- match any english characters

I have tried the following two regexes:

```
[a-zA-Z\\s{2,]]*|[a-zA-Z{2,}]
```

and

```
[a-zA-Z\\s]*|[a-zA-Z].{2,}
```

But they do not work. Can anyone help me understand how to write this regex?

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings you want to match? From your description, it sounds like, for example, `a` should not match, but `ab` and `ab ab` would. Am I understanding your goal correctly?

Comment: Yes, correctly you understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidated Restrictions:
Match strings consisting of at least 1 length 2+ character sequence restricted to the english characters (not sure if this is exactly what you want, but hopefully it will suffice):

```
regex = "^(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s*)+$"
```

"^": must begin with
"(?:...)": group, but do not capture 
"\s": whitespace
"*": 0 or more
"[...]": character class
"[a-zA-Z]": restricts characters to lower/uppercase a,b,...,y,z
"{2,": 2 or more of the proceeding
"+": 1 or more
"$": must end here